# Removing parent node in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am able to remove parent node in XML but white spaces are still there and i see some hard code is also removed.

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDIDATA>
   <MetaData>
      <Sender>NCBK</Sender>
      <MessageType>ABCDE</MessageType>
      <TranType>INT</TranType>
      <ValueDate>220427</ValueDate>
      <CorpReferenceNumber>0000JF4HHwBHLcKD</CorpReferenceNumber>
      <ExecutionDate>2204271029</ExecutionDate>
      <AccountNumber>08563275789</AccountNumber>
      <Status>OK</Status>
      <DeliveryStatus>OK</DeliveryStatus>
      <MessageDescription>Credit Notification</MessageDescription>
      <SequenceNumber>220400100000305</SequenceNumber>
      <TransactionReference>100000305</TransactionReference>
      <ErrorDescription>-</ErrorDescription>
      <Account>20817167000105</Account>
      <TimeStamp>2022-04-27T10:28:01</TimeStamp>
   </MetaData>
   <Payload><![CDATA[]]></Payload>
</EDIDATA>
```

**I am getting below output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDIDATA> **Getting space below EDIDATA:**
   <Sender>NCBK</Sender>
   <MessageType>CRNTF</MessageType>
   <TranType>INT</TranType>
   <ValueDate>220427</ValueDate>
   <CorpReferenceNumber>8HplxF4HHwBHLcKD</CorpReferenceNumber>
   <ExecutionDate>2204271029</ExecutionDate>
   <AccountNumber>20817167000105</AccountNumber>
   <Status>OK</Status>
   <DeliveryStatus>OK</DeliveryStatus>
   <MessageDescription>Credit Notification</MessageDescription>
   <SequenceNumber>220427100000305</SequenceNumber>
   <TransactionReference>100000305</TransactionReference>
   <ErrorDescription>-</ErrorDescription>
   <Account>20817167000105</Account>
   <TimeStamp>2022-04-27T10:28:01</TimeStamp> **Getting space below TimeStamp:**
   <Payload /> **Payload is empty after xslt**
</EDIDATA>
```

**Using below xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="MetaData">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone suggest what needs to be corrected here:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the extra white space, you can add this instruction:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

to the top level of your stylesheet.

---

FYI, the `Payload` element is empty in the original XML too. If you want `Payload` to continue using CDATA for its text, you should change the `xsl:output` instruction to:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="Payload"/>
```

but I doubt your processor will bother to implement it when there is no actual text.

---

P.S. I don't see why you need to use:

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:copy>
```

Comment: An alternative solution is to use `select="*"` in the xsl:apply-templates instruction of the `match="MetaData"` template rule.

Comment: `cdata-section-elements` shouldn't affect an empty element. The spec says "If the expanded QName of the parent of a text node is a member of the list, then the text node MUST be output as a CDATA section"; but where the element is empty, there is no text node so this rule isn't triggered.